# for loop return wrong username from firebase database but correct coordinate

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I using the list view to display the tutor from tlocation node in database with the same subject as student selected. Now I got problem when retrieving the data, it gave me the 2 users coordinate of the same subject but display with the same name.

Here's my database structure
[image]

And here's my code

```
 scref = db.getReference("users");
 tref = db.getReference("tlocation");
 sref = db.getReference("slocation");

 ul.clear();

 scref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

 ps = dataSnapshot.child(un).child("position").getValue().toString();

 if (ps.equalsIgnoreCase("student")){

 Query q = tref.orderByChild("subject").equalTo(ssubject);
 q.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
           @Override
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           for (DataSnapshot u: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                 susername = u.getKey();

 tref.child(susername).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        sula = dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue().toString();
        sulo = dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue().toString();

        Location cl1 = new Location("");
        lat1 =  Float.parseFloat(la);
        lon1 = Float.parseFloat(lo);
        cl1.setLatitude(lat1);
        cl1.setLongitude(lon1);

        Location cl2 = new Location("");
        lat2 =  Float.parseFloat(sula);
        lon2 = Float.parseFloat(sulo);
        cl2.setLatitude(lat2);
        cl2.setLongitude(lon2);

        float distance = cl1.distanceTo(cl2);
        int i = 0;
  ul.add(new UserLocationData(i++, susername, String.valueOf(distance)));

  sla = new searchList(getApplicationContext(), ul);
              searchlist.setAdapter(sla);

         }



                                        @Override
                                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                        }
                                    });
                                }


                            }

                            @Override
         public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });

                    }else if (ps.equalsIgnoreCase("tutor")){



                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });// end of scref
```

Here's my result
[image]

So please advice me on this question. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps using proper variable names would help you find the problem.

Comment: @Ridcully you're right and I suddenly found out problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens. addValueEventListener get call twice. if u don't want repeated value u can clear the ArrayList value inside the addValueEventListener method. so that u won't get repeated value. u can also set an if condition if u have multiple addValueEventListener for the same ArrayList.

Comment: i just want twice since their got the same subject but the name repeated.

Comment: yah yah and I suddenly solved it. Very appreciated that you give me your suggestion.